# Querying SharePoint search for all departments with REST API

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, ajax

I currently have an ajax request set up in my javascript to call the search API but this only gives me departments matching whatever I input for `query`:

```
$.ajax(
    {
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='Department:"
         + query
         + "*'&selectproperties='Department'&sourceid='<removed>'&sortlist='Department:ascending'",
         method: "GET",
         headers: {
             "accept": "application/xml",
         },
             success: onSuccess,
             error: onError
    }
);
```

How can I query search so that I get ALL departments back? I can do the filtering for distinct departments once I get the data back, but I don't want to search for a particular department. I want all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you tried Department:* and that did not work, you could try to search by content type. If Department is a site column, you could request all items that have the Content Type that contains that column.

Comment: No, `Department:*` returns no results. Department is not a site column, it is part of the search schema and is grabbed from a user profile (which is sync'd from AD). The crawler grabs this when it crawls `sps3` on a particular web app.

Answer (score 0):

That query won't work because you're querying all items that HAVE a department. If you just want the department, get it from the Managed metadata service. User departments, job titles, and location are synchronized from AD and pumped into the mms app > People > Department.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a specific Department in your Query. This works for me:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='Department'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=100
```